# Problem with adding checkmark/radio button in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I've been trying to find a way to add a radio button/checkmark for a few hours now, but I can't find anything online that tells me how to do it with a float layout. Not sure if I need to completely rewrite my code or not, would really appreciate some help.
Most of the tutorials I've seen requires the code to be in grid layout/box layout. I can't change my code to that though, otherwise all the placements of everything gets messed up.

python file:

```
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

class MyWidget(Widget):
       pass

class CustomButtonApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return FloatLayout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    CustomButtonApp().run()
```

.kv file:

```
    slide_text: slider_label
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: (255/255, 170/255, 235/255)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
        Line:
            width: 2
            rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height


    Button:
        size_hint: (.275, .2)
        pos_hint: {"x":.066, "y":.05}
        background_normal: ''
        background_color: 1, .3, .4, .85
        font_size: 50
        bold: True
        color: 200/255, 0/255, 70/255, 1
        text: "Update"


    Button:
        size_hint: (.275, .2)
        pos_hint: {"x":.366, "y":.05}
        background_normal: ''
        background_color: 1, .3, .4, .85
        font_size: 50
        bold: True
        color: 200/255, 0/255, 70/255, 1
        text: "Copy"

    Button:
        size_hint: (.275, .2)
        pos_hint: {"x":.666, "y":.05}
        background_normal: ''
        background_color: 1, .3, .4, .85
        font_size: 50
        bold: True
        color: 200/255, 0/255, 70/255, 1
        text: "Credits"

    Slider:
        value_track: True
        value_track_color: 1, .3, .4, .85
        size_hint: (.65, .2)
        pos_hint: {"x": .205, "y": .43}
        id: slider
        min: 0
        max: 100
        step: 1
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        #on_value: root.slide_it(*args)


    Label:
        background_color: 1, 0, 0, 1
        size_hint: (.275, .2)
        pos_hint: {"x": .79, "y": .435}
        id: slider_label
        text: str(int(slider.value))
        font_size: 50
        bold: True
        color: 200/255, 0/255, 70/255, 1

    Slider:
        value_track: True
        value_track_color: 1, .3, .4, .85
        size_hint: (.65, .2)
        pos_hint: {"x": .205, "y": .63}
        id: slider2
        min: 0
        max: 100
        step: 1
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        #on_value: root.slide_it(*args)


    Label:
        background_color: 1, 0, 0, 1
        size_hint: (.275, .2)
        pos_hint: {"x": .79, "y": .635}
        id: slider2_label
        text: str(int(slider2.value))
        font_size: 50
        bold: True
        color: 200/255, 0/255, 70/255, 1

    Label:
        background_color: 1, 0, 0, 1
        size_hint: (.275, .2)
        pos_hint: {"x": -.035, "y": .635}
        font_size: 40
        text: "Volume:"
        bold: True
        color: 200/255, 0/255, 70/255, 1

    Label:
        background_color: 1, 0, 0, 1
        size_hint: (.275, .2)
        pos_hint: {"x": -.02, "y": .435}
        text: "Speed:"
        font_size: 40
        bold: True
        color: 200/255, 0/255, 70/255, 1

    #Checkbox:
     #   size_hint: None, none
      #  size: "48dp", "48dp"
       # pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
    # Doesn't work?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The start of your `.kv` file is not provided so it is not clear if you have specified the layout.  I will assume you have specified this as `<FloatLayout>`.

A checkbox will be added but it may seem to be invisible as it has no background or label.  You can specify a label and the background colour of the checkbox as follows:

```
<FloatLayout>:

    # other components

    Label:
        text: 'My Checkbox'
        size_hint_x: .80
        font_size: 20

    CheckBox:
        canvas.before:
            # checkbox border
            Color:
                rgb: 1, 0, 0

            Rectangle:
                pos:self.center_x - 10, self.center_y - 10
                size:[20, 20]

            # checkbox background
            Color:
                rgb: 0, 0, 0

            Rectangle:
                pos:self.center_x - 9, self.center_y - 9
                size:[18, 18]

        size: '48dp', '48dp'
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
```

The `canvas.before` part specifies the appearance of the checkbox. In this case, a square with a red border and black background.